# Rails: New migration but nil in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have created a new migration:

```
class AddSignatureToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :users, :signature, :text
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :users, :signature
  end
end
```

Now my usertable has a new column called signature.
On my edit page I wrote:

```
<h1>Editing user</h1>
<% form_for(@user) do |f| %>



  <%= f.error_messages %>
  <div class="form-wrapper">
    <p>
      <label for="email">Email</label>
      <%= f.text_field :email %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="user_signature">Signature</label>
      <%= f.text_area(:signature, :value => @user.signature) %>
    </p>
    <div class="form-submit">
      <%= f.submit 'Update', :class => "form-submit-button" %>
    </div>

  </div>


<% end %>
```

But this won't work.
In my controller I always get nil as value for signature. Any ideas why?

```
  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
        puts @user.signature #always nil
        flash[:notice] = 'User was successfully updated.'
        format.html { redirect_to(@user) }
        format.xml  { head :ok }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @user.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found my error!
In my user model, I had

```
attr_accessible :login, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
```

I added :signature and now it's working!

```
attr_accessible :login, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :signature
```

Answer (score 1):

Check to make sure you ran the migration for the proper environment (development, production)

```
RAILS_ENV=development rake db:migrate
```

This is the default, but you may be setting the environment somewhere. I think you'd get a method not found error if you hadn't, but just be sure, I've been hot by this before.

Next, if you're using the mongrel/webrick, try using the debugger, by starting the server with:

```
./script/server --debugger --environment=development
```

And then in your controller:

```
  respond_to do |format|
      debugger
      if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
        puts @user.signature #always nil
  ...
```

And check what params is here, specifically params[:user][:signature], make sure it's getting passed correctly.

Lastly, in the view, all you need is:

```
  <%= f.label :signature %>
  <%= f.text_area :signature %>
```

The value will already be the current value since you're calling the form on @user in the form_for. The explicit setting of :value might be interfering somewhere

Comment: Well, I migrated the mirgration to my database and the column exists already. I Tried to write 
  <%= f.label :signature %>
  <%= f.text_area :signature %>

without any success. But I think it doesn't matter weather I write 
      <label for="user_signature">Signature</label>
      <%= f.text_area(:signature, :value => @user.signature) %>

or 

  <%= f.label :signature %>
  <%= f.text_area :signature %>
right?

do I have to write something in my user model? I don't think so, but you never know... I am new at rails, sorry.

Comment: Are you using a newer version of Rails (2.3.x)? You shouldn't need to write anything in your user model, activerecord sets up the methods for you automatically.

Comment: Yea, I use V2.3.2 and Netbeans as IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Two quick questions-

1. Why are we looking at edit.html.erb and update here? Did you already create this record with new.html.erb and create?
2. Why do you have `<%= f.text_area(:signature, :value => @user.signature) %>` instead of just `<%= f.text_area :signature %>`

Comment: 1. Yes, my user is created in a registration form (users/new.html.erb)

2. Now I am using <%= f.text_area :signature %> but this won't work after all.

Comment: What do you get if your try puts params[:user][:signature] in your controller?

Comment: When I puts params[:user][:signature] in my update function, I get the right value. I am new to Rails, so how to go on? What's the difference between puts params[:user][:signature] and puts @user.signature?

Comment: Well, it looks like update_attributes isn't putting the params into the @user object. Very odd.. do you have any special handlers or anything in your User model?

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure, you have run `rake db:migrate` to run the migration, yes?

Comment: yea, I ran rake db:migrate and the column exists in my database
(select signature from users;)